# Unbounded spectra and operators

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

In a paper I have encountered the following non-autonomous infinite dimensional dynamical system:
$$
    \frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix}
    f \\
    g
    \end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -t^{-2} \Delta_{S^2} & -2 t^{-1}
    \end{pmatrix}}_{A(t)}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f \\
    g
    \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $f,g \in C^\infty(S^2)$ for $t>0$, and $\Delta_{S^2}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the sphere.
The operator $A(t)$ has unbounded spectrum in both directions, and therefore the above problem is said to be ill-posed, *meaning one cannot expect a solution to exist forward or backward in time for generic initial data*. I am not an expert in functional analysis, and the only thing I know is that if $A(t)$ is unbounded, it is not easy to prove that an abstract Cauchy problem is well posed. Does the fact that $A(t)$ have an unbounded spectrum automatically imply that it is an unbounded operator? And if not, why does the above property imply that the problem is ill-posed? Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Bounded operators (on some Banach space) have bounded spectra, so the answer to the first question is yes.